# How to reference system.drawing in Visual Studio 2010 Express?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, drawing

I'm somewhat new to this and I am under the impression that to draw a rectangle that I've created, I need to use system.drawing.graphics. Thing is, I get the error

"The type or namespace name 'drawing' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

and when I right click the References folder in the solution explorer, system.drawing is nowhere to be found. So I'm not exactly sure how to move forward in drawing a rectangle.

Comment: The C# language is case sensitive.  It is Drawing, not drawing.  Adding a reference to a .NET assembly as well as starting your project with the correct project template is covered in any introductory book on .NET programming.  Avoid trial and error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Namespace should be available to you no matter the version of VS2010.  Right click "References", "Add Reference...", ".NET" tab, sort by component name and select "System.Drawing" and "OK".

If it doesn't show then you might want to look into your build properties on your project and see what framework you're targeting (2.0, 3.5, 4.0, etc...)